# How to return from activity to a specific fragment in navigation bottom

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, mobile, navigationbar

**hello guys,**
I'm developing an android app in which I need your help.
in this app, I have a bottom nav bar so I can communicate between 4 fragments A, B, C, and D.
I put the A fragment as the default home fragment.
the problem that, if I want to start my navigationBottom activity (A is the default home fragment after LogInstrong text)
I want to start it with a fragment C for example.

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav"
    app:startDestination="@id/account">
```

Comment: can you please share your activity code, and also class code in which you implemented  Bottomnavigation.?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Stackoverflow :)

**Solution**
Add these lines in your First Activity(From which you are moving to BottomNav Class)

```
`Intent intent = new Intent(YourActivity.this, BottomNavAvtivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("FromMainActivity", "1");
        startActivity(intent);`
```

Next,In your Second Activity(Class implementing BottomNav) write the below code in onCreate() of BottomNavigation class:

```
Intent i = getIntent();
    String data = i.getStringExtra("FromReservation");

    if (data != null && data.contentEquals("1")) {

      yourBottomNav.setFragment(yourFragment);
}
```

Comment: hello, and thanks for your explanation 
but this stopped the app of working

Comment: bottomNavigationView=(BottomNavigationView)findViewById(R.id.Nav);
        Intent i = getIntent();
        String data = i.getStringExtra("FromMainActivity");

        if (data != null && data.contentEquals("1")) {

            replace(new Help());
            //bottomNavigationView.setFragment(R.id.help);
        }

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with conditional navigation, I would recommend this medium article: https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/navigation-conditional-navigation-e82d7e4905f0

Especially the section around this code snippet (copy-pasted from the medium article) which shows how to change the default screen depending on a shared preferences value:

```
donutListViewModel.isFirstRun().observe(viewLifecycleOwner) { s ->
    if (s == UserPreferencesRepository.Selection.NOT_SELECTED) {
        val navController = findNavController()
        navController.navigate(
            DonutListDirections.actionDonutListToSelectionFragment()
        )
    }
}
```